# Touch count detect and perform function

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, uitapgesturerecognizer

> tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
>   action:@selector(handleTapGesture:)];
>       tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
>       tapGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
>
> ```
> [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
> [tapGesture release];
> ```

and

```
- (void)handleTapGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {

     if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized) {
  // handling code
        NSLog(@"We got double tap here");
        DashBoardViewController*   dashboardObj = [[DashBoardViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DashBoardViewController" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:dashboardObj animated:YES];
 }
```

what i am trying to do is , i want to call 2 different events on single tap and on double tap.
So how can i detect when tap==1 and tap==2?
Double tap is recognised in my code, but i am not sure, how to find and work,when a single tap is find.

Thanks

Comment: You could use a timer.  Start the timer when you get a tap. If the timer expires you know you need to act on a a single tap. If you get another tap before the timer expires, you know you are dealing with a double tap.

Comment: could you plz help me on that...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may give u a soln

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDoubleTap:)];

[doubleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
[singleTap setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];

[self.view addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];

- (void)handleSingleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
// single tap action
}

- (void)handleDoubleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
   // double tap action
}
```

or u have to use NSTimer as darren pointed to validate the single touch.

In the method,

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

Comment: Thanks Nazik. The problem with above code is, on detecting double tap,it first call single tap function and than the double tap function.

Answer (score 0):

Following seems to a good post about touch in iOS.

http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/07/10/touching-and-gesturing-on-the-iphone/

Comment: Yasir,i am looking for iOS :)